# Help required for a logic to represent in code

Tags: apex, soql

I am a fresher and i am not able to represent in coding format for the previous week logic.
The requirement is i have a date field called funding date.I have to fetch the records where this date field have previous week's date.
For example,

```
SELECT fund__c,amount__c where funding_Date__c=previous week.
```

In the query,in the place of previous week i dont know what logic i have to use so that i can fetch when that date field has previous week dates.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [date literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) LAST_WEEK:

```
SELECT Fund__c, Amount__c FROM Funding__c WHERE Funding_Date__c = LAST_WEEK
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Date Formats and Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) in salesforce.

```
SELECT fund__c,amount__c where funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use something like this `SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > LAST_WEEK`

```
SELECT fund__c,amount__c where funding_Date__c=LAST_WEEK
```